# How to rename the header column based upon another file in R

Tags: r

I am working in R. I have two text files - one a data file and the other an annotation file. The data file has a header row. The annotation file has descriptions for the headers, whether a header is "Normal" or "Defective". I want to update the header in the data file by appending "Normal-" or "Defective-" to the header. For example if the header is "abc123" and the corresponding entry in the annotation file is "Normal" then I have to rename the header as "Normal-abc123". I have to do this for all the headers.

Thanks

Data file:

```
           GSM146796        GSM146798  GSM146779  GSM146781  GSM146783
1007_s_at     2107.7 9898.3406‌​9121213     1940.2     2608.8     1837.2
```

Annotation file:

```
GSM146798 = Value for GSM146798: Stage 2, PT1, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146796 = Value for GSM146796: Stage 2, PT12, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146779 = Value for GSM146779: Stage 1, PT2, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146781 = Value for GSM146781: Stage 1, PT3, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146783 = Value for GSM146783: Stage 1, PT4, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the actual data in your question?

Comment: GSM146778 GSM146780 GSM146782 GSM146784 GSM146786 GSM146789 GSM146790 GSM146792 GSM146794 GSM146798 GSM146796 GSM146779 GSM146781 GSM146783 GSM146785 GSM146787 GSM146788 GSM146791 GSM146799 GSM146793 GSM146795 GSM146797
1007_s_at 1942.1 2358.3 2465.2 2732.9 1952.2 2048.3 2109 3005.1 2568.1 9898.34069121213 2107.7 1940.2 2608.8 1837.2 1559.2 2111.6 2641 1972.7 10191.6713947012 1737.2 1636.1 2718.4

Comment: Please edit that into your question because it is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Annotation:GSM146798 = Value for GSM146798: Stage 2, PT1, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146796 = Value for GSM146796: Stage 2, PT12, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146779 = Value for GSM146779: Stage 1, PT2, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146781 = Value for GSM146781: Stage 1, PT3, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
GSM146783 = Value for GSM146783: Stage 1, PT4, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium

Comment: @user466663 - please take note of Thomas' comment. Neither of your comments are particularly helpful when pasted as big blobs. *Carefully* formatting your question will allow us all to make sense of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# read in annotation
annotation <- read.table(text="GSM146798 = Value for GSM146798: Stage 2, PT1, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
                    GSM146796 = Value for GSM146796: Stage 2, PT12, Normal (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
                    GSM146779 = Value for GSM146779: Stage 1, PT2, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
                    GSM146781 = Value for GSM146781: Stage 1, PT3, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium
                    GSM146783 = Value for GSM146783: Stage 1, PT4, Defective (HG-U133A); src: Human Renal Epithelium", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# read in table
data <- read.table(text="           GSM146796        GSM146798  GSM146779  GSM146781  GSM146783
                    1007_s_at     2107.7 9898.3406??9121213     1940.2     2608.8     1837.2", header=TRUE)
```

This is pretty straightforward with `sapply`. I imagine there might even be a more straightforward vectorized way, but this should get you what you want.

```
newname <- sapply(names(data), function(x) 
                    paste(annotation$V9[annotation$V1==x],x,sep="-") )
names(data) <- newname
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you please suggest me good books for this type of R code. All my R books deal only with graphing.

Comment: For these types of tasks the online help files and [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) are often your best bets.